# How to merge 2 similar ontologies with OWL API

Tags: owl, owl-api

Lets says we have an ontology A and 2 different people start modifying it - e.g. adding different classes, new properties to existing classes. At the end of the day we have 2 ontologies A1 and A2. Now mine is A1 and I want to make sure that changes from A2 are incorporated into my ontology A1. There might be simple cases where I just need to attach a new class, but there might be difficult ones when 2 users modify a specific property for a class and there needs to be an option to ask me (the user) which property to keep. 
Is there a solution for this type of merge in OWL API? I found this questions, but I don't think it covers what I need to achieve: [How to properly merge 2 ontologies with OWL API 4 or 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888449/how-to-properly-merge-2-ontologies-with-owl-api-4-or-3-5)

Comment: You're talking about *data fusion*. This has to be done by the application and is still a research topic as part of data integration in general. There is no such built-in in OWL API - and for good reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say that it has to be done by the application - you mean that I have to program it from scratch by myself? Or shouldn't I even attempt doing this for some reasons? Could you please give more details...

Comment: OWL API is an API to work with the core entities of the W3C OWL recommendation. What you're asking for is a more complex use-case on top of OWL, thus, there is no need to have this thing inside the API.

Comment: No, I think you have just to search for "ontology integration" and should find some pointers. If your use-case is really that simple as described, then you just have to check for the different types of changes resp. axioms and call the appropriate method if one of your "fusion rules" is triggered.

Comment: Note, your task might be somehow different from the standard ontology integration, as you want to merge the changesets as far as I understood. This goes even somehow in the direction of ontology evolution. But as I said, you should try to keep it as simple as possible and write down in advance the requirements and possible cases that could happen

Comment: *Ontology Fusion* is probably the most related phrase in your case, yet it's not defined on changesets but n different ontologies. Have fun!

Comment: The question you linked is enough to merge the non conflicting axioms. The difficult part in your use case comes from first detecting which axioms are conflicting and then how to merge them - where you want manual intervention, but I assume you'd like to automate the choice to some extent. Conflict detection will likely be ontology and application specific, so some examples of such conflicts would help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Ignazio, the example is rdfs:label "label1" and rdfs:label "label2". When such conflict is encountered I would like at least to be able to save this in a log (along with the class name). Then I can go through the log and work from there. Or, as we go through all the conflicts, have a user to answer the question which option he wants to save - first, second, or combined.

Comment: Interresting, you choose one of the rare relation (rdfs:label) where reasoning will almost never see a conflicting problem. On this relation you have to code 'detection' & 'resolution' using the raw-axioms.